# Homodyne receiver bandwidth

Tags: receiver, vco, sdr

I understand that most, if not all, SDRs use direct conversion, since an SDR can receive several channels simultaneously. So how does tuning the VCO work?

Let's assume for simplicity that I need to receive 3 channels simultaneously located at 10 MHz, 15 MHz and 30 MHz. What is the correct approach here? Do I tune the VCO at the middle of the total bandwidth at 20 MHz and bandpass also at 20 MHz to receive all 3 channels?

I want to understand if there is an approach to achieve the instantaneous bandwidth with multi channels. It comes to mind how a spectrum analyzer works with a ramp voltage to control the VCO for sweeping, but then that's not instantaneous.

Comment: What makes you say that SDRs can receive several channels simultaneously, and other non SDRs cannot ? By definition an SDR is is a radio communication system where components that have been traditionally implemented in analog hardware (e.g. mixers, filters, amplifiers, modulators/demodulators, detectors, etc.) are instead programmable by means of software or an embedded system. Just because the SDR is in a sense programmable, does not mean that automatically it can receive many simultaneous channels, more than say a conventional analog non SDR radio.

Comment: this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfbuOT_RawI

Answer (score 0):

By definition an SDR is is a radio communication system where components that have been traditionally implemented in analog hardware (e.g. mixers, filters, amplifiers, modulators/demodulators, detectors, etc.) are instead programmable by means of some external software or by an embedded system. Just because the SDR is in a sense programmable, does not mean that automatically it can receive many simultaneous channels, more than say a conventional analog non SDR radio. Its overall sophistication will depend on how many programmable features are implemented in physical hardware that would allow one to program and reconfigure many of the radio receiver's and signal processing stages etc.

In your case if the SDR has programmable frequency sythesizer(s) and receiver filter(s) then, yes you could set a particular receiver frequency to receive on and also the receiver filter, IF filters etc. Perhaps many more settings are programmable, such as receiver filter bandwidth, shape, etc (or perhaps only basic settings are programmable).

Same goes for transmission, where many aspects of radio communication transmistter may be programmable, such as the modulation format(s) (say FSK, or ASK etc.) and the modulation parameters and maybe even the various transmission filters to filter out the harmonics ... This again may or may not be available for your particular SDR, and you may still require to adapt it to your needs using classic analog signal processing components that you would not be able to programm "on-the-fly" so to speak ...

You may take a look at the various SDR chip-sets that Ti, AD, Maxim etc propose to see the level of "programmability" that will suit your requirements for the application in mind. More flexibility/programmability will generally also mean more cost and more complexity for you to use it.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to understand if there is an approach to achieve the <Instantaneous bandwidth> with multi channels , it come to mind how the spectrum analyzer work with a ramp voltage to control the VCO for sweeping but then that's not <Instantaneous>

Comment: As I mentioned before, it all depends what is available with your SDR. Some extra components may or may not be necessary. If youé SDR does not include a fast enough ADC then you will need to add it. Some other SDR will have such broad-band ADC, but may still require an up-conversion and/or down-conversion mixer etc. for tuning your 20MHz signal to the ADC. Many of the SDR chip-sets do include a schematic diagram outlining the various signal processing stages that are included...

Comment: @Hazehh what is the maximum bandwidth of your SDR? It must be high enough to capture all of the signals you want without distorting them - not just their center frequencies at the very edges. So 20MHz plus a few.